# Is there a method to check the UICollectionView item drag cancellation if the item wasn't moved?

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I use drag and drop to rearrange a collectionView. When I start the drag, I change the collectionView visualization. To change it back I need a method which will be executed in any case. Now if I start the drag and release the touch immediately, none of the following methods are executed:

```
not this:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  dragSessionDidEnd session: UIDragSession)

not this:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidEnd session: UIDropSession)

not this:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator)
```

Thank you.

Comment: From Apple documentation it seems that dragSessionDidEnd will be called either when a drop occurs or when the session is aborted https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdragdelegate/2897477-collectionview

Comment: Ha. I just realized that it cannot be ended as it starts only on movement — so, if you just picked an item, and even its preview was generated, it doesn't mean that you started the drag. Thus, the problem is that I can't get an updated cell state before I get the preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the standard UICollectionViewDragDelegate implementation, you can react to the cell state change using the `func dragStateDidChange(_ dragState: UICollectionViewCellDragState)` **of the cell class itself** like:

```
override func dragStateDidChange(_ dragState: UICollectionViewCellDragState) {

    switch dragState {

    case .none:
        //
    case .lifting:
        //
    case .dragging:
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a similar method on `UICollectionView` that a collectionView can respond to when its cells get lifted? Or we should propagate this event from the cell to its collectionView by ourselves?

Comment: When the `UICollectionView` conforms to `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` protocol, you can use `func collectionView(UICollectionView, dragSessionWillBegin: UIDragSession)` to get notifications that a drag session is about to begin for the collection view.

Comment: `func collectionView(UICollectionView, dragSessionWillBegin: UIDragSession)` doesn't get called for "lifting" state

Answer (score 1):

From the WWDC "[Introducing Drag and Drop](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/203/)" video it seems that the right place to handle the lift and its cancellation is the `dragInteraction(_:willAnimateLiftWith:session:)` method.

[image]

Comment: This won't work with `UICollectionViewDragDelegate`.