# How to remove 'ghost' cell during UICollectionView drag/drop, and make moving cell opaque?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uikit

I'm trying to implement drag/drop mechanics in my UICollectionView, very similar to reordering components of a shortcut in the Shortcuts app.

As of now, the behavior is that when you begin a drag, there's a transparent view of the cell left behind while another transparent view of the cell moves with the finger.

I want to get rid of the 'ghost' cell, and make the moving cell completely opaque.

Here's my drag/drop behavior (largely taken from [this post](https://itnext.io/how-to-drag-drop-uicollectionview-cells-by-utilizing-dropdelegate-and-dragdelegate-6e3512327202))

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let item = itemData[indexPath.item]
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item.title as NSString)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    dragItem.localObject = item


    return [dragItem]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

    if collectionView.hasActiveDrag {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    }

    return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {

    var destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
    if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
        destinationIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    else {
        let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row - 1, section: 0)
    }

    reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)

}

fileprivate func reorderItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator,
                              destinationIndexPath: IndexPath,
                              collectionView: UICollectionView) {

    if let item = coordinator.items.first,
        let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath {

        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.itemData.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
            self.itemData.insert(item.dragItem.localObject as! PlanItem, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
            collectionView.insertItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
        }, completion: nil)

        coordinator.drop(item.dragItem, toItemAt: destinationIndexPath)
    }
}
```

[image: Here's an image describing what I want]

Answer (score 2):

not sure if question still actual, but if so:
here is how you can handle cell drag state:

[Is there a method to check the UICollectionView item drag cancellation if the item wasn't moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681643/is-there-a-method-to-check-the-uicollectionview-item-drag-cancellation-if-the-it)

just do it hidden on drag, via DispatchQueue.main.async {}

and make again visible on .none state. works for me :)

Comment: This doesn't explain how to hide the ghost cell though.